# Probleme with display data in javafx textarea

Tags: javafx, textarea

i'm a java beginner (and french:)).I make a gui with javafx to communicate via serial port to a 3d printer. In my code i can send and receive data. The received data is displayed in the java console but i'd like to display this data in a textarea. And i didn't manage. i've no code error but nothing in the textarea. here is my code:

```
@FXML
private TextArea rxArea = new TextArea();
```

in the same controller class :

```
public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {

        if(event.isRXCHAR() &&event.getEventValue() > 0){
            try {

              String  data = serialPort.readString(event.getEventValue());
               System.out.println(data); //work
               rxArea.appendText(data);  // not work

            }
            catch (SerialPortException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
        }
}
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: It's not really possible to answer your question with just the code snippet you posted: you should consider creating a [MCVE] that demonstrates the problem. However, it is *always* a mistake to initialize a field that is annotated `@FXML`. The annotation indicates that the field is supposed to be initialized by the `FXMLLoader` when the FXML file is loaded. Remove the `= new TextArea()` from the declaration of `rxArea`. If that causes an exception to be thrown, then you have some information as to what is going wrong.

Comment: ok thanks, i'll try to post an example. If i remove = new TextArea(), i have a NullPointerException error

Comment: The NPE means either that the `fx:id` in the FXML file does not match the field name, or that you are not calling `serialEvent` on the actual controller created by the `FXMLLoader` when you load the FXML. Impossible to tell which from the code currently posted. In either case, it means `rxArea` does not reference the `TextArea` created in the FXML file. So when you include `= new TextArea()`, you create a *new* text area, which is never displayed, and you are appending text to that text area. Since the text area is never displayed, you don't see the text.

Comment: Probably there is also an issue with the thread you use to update the GUI. If the `serialEvent` method is triggered on a thread other than the JavaFX application thread you should use `Platform.runLater` for updating the `TextArea`...

Comment: you're right, serialevent is not created from fxml. I don't know how to put an event listener to the textarea from scenebuilder. In the code list there are mouse event, keyboard event...